# Acceleo creating a UI launcher not found

Tags: user-interface, acceleo

I use acceleo 3 with eclipse modeling tools 3.7. I follow this link http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started in the final step " Creating a UI launcher " - I don't have Acceleo Model to text .

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch a new Eclipse with this plugin installed in order for the menu to show itself. The last screenshot of the getting started is to show the result of this plugin being installed.

Use Run > Run Configurations... then in the popup, double click "Eclipse application" and click "Run". A new Eclipse will be launched with all plugins you had in your workspace installed. In this new Eclipse, you should have the "Acceleo Model-To-Text" menu.